# What is the performance overhead of Popen in python

Tags: python, native, popen

compared to invoking a python library function that does the same thing. 
I've some legacy code that uses Popen to invoke a executable with some parameters.

Now there a python library that supports that same function. 
I was wondering what the performance implications are.

Comment: Actual overhead is likely to be OS-dependent.  If you want to know exactly how expensive, try timing it both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forking a separate process to do something is almost always much more expensive than calling a function that does the same thing. But if that Python function is very inefficient, and the OS forks new processes quickly (i.e., is a UNIX variant,) you could imagine a rare case where this is not true -- but it will definitely be rare.